# Change Date format Inside span tag using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a date inside span and I want to change its format. Ex. from "August 14, 2022 6:36 am" to "8/14/2022" How to do this using javascript?

```html
<span class="question-date">August 18, 2022 10:08 am</span>
```

Comment: How do you output that content? If it's static, just do `el.innerText = '8/14/2022'`

Comment: I want to create a function in js to update the text inside span so I won't need change the structure of my php

Comment: I have dynamic values.

Comment: You can use [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Make use of `Date`:

```
const spanElement = document.querySelector(".question-date")
const currentDate = new Date(spanElement.innerHTML)
spanElement.innerHTML = currentDate.toLocaleDateString("en-US")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function:

```js
function convertDate(date_string) {
  let a = new Date(date_string);
  let b = a.toLocaleDateString().split("/");
  return b[1] + "/" + b[0] + "/" + b[2]
}

console.log(convertDate("August 14, 2022 6:36 am"))
```